# Mysql two where condition on to total one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table suspended_bills where I want to get a sum of the total but I want the total in a single query.check this query

```
SELECT  date, (select sum(total) where type='bill') as bill_total, (select 
sum(total) where type='quotation') as quotation_total from suspended_bills 
group by YEAR(date),MONTH(date)
```

I know this is the wrong query but I want to know the solution to get the sum of bill and quotation in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select YEAR(date), MONTH(date), 
       sum(case when type = 'bill' then total else 0 end) as bill_total, 
       sum(case when type = 'quotation' then total else 0 end) as quotation_total
from suspended_bills 
group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```